# Avoid SQL injection inserting thousands of records in seconds

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am under heavy attack some one inserting thousands of records in my database.

Checkout my codes below I am using.

```
<?php
include_once 'files/config.php';
$q = trim(!empty($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : null;
$key = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($q));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,title,size,category,url FROM data WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$key') ORDER BY MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$key') DESC LIMIT 200");
?>

// some divs data goes here

<?php
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES('{$key}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1");   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$title = $row['title'];
$size = $row['size'];
$title = strip_tags($title);
?>
```

How to avoid this attack inserting thousands of fake records into my database within a minute?

Comment: Do some research and try rate limiting or log IPs

Comment: @Valkyrie how do I find the attackers IPs? I am using Linux Debian Wheezy 7.9

Comment: Does this operation lend itself to something like [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)? Or is there a login required prior to invoking the INSERT operation?

Comment: No its direct search input and output from the database no login no reCAPTCHA required.